# Does ‘half the half circle’ make sense?

Tags: adjectives, determiners

Can ‘half the half circle’ be used instead of 1/4 circle? Or what should I say to express this? I guess a half half circle or half of a half circle?

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quadrant

Comment: @Kate Bunting Half the half circle is wrong?

Comment: You asked how to express it - _a quadrant_ is the most exact term. You could say _half a semicircle_, but I don't recommend using the word _half_ twice.

Comment: @Kate Bunting You know, I need extra information to use generally... 1/8 triangle 1/16 square etc.

Comment: If you are asking me what to call an eighth of a triangle - I'm no mathematician, but as far as I know there is no special word for it.

Comment: There you go an eighth of a triangle thanks

Comment: In the future please ask the real question you care about - in this case, about eights and sixteenths and so on, not just about halves of halves. That will help us give useful answers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem   @KateBunting is correct that there is no special way to name the fractions you ask about.

Comment: If you already have a particular half-circle that you've referred to as "the half circle", and you want half of that half-circle, then yes, "half the half circle" is great. If you just want a quarter-circle without already having a particular half-circle, then just say "quarter-circle".

Answer (score 1):

Just use "a quarter circle". Example https://study.com/academy/lesson/quarter-circles-calculating-area-perimeter-radius.html

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking a quarter of a circle is a quadrant. The various other sectors of a circle which have special names are outlined in the [Wikipedia article on Circular sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector) and they are sextant (sixth of a circle) and octant (eighth of a circle).

That assumes when you ask about a circle you mean the disc not just the periphery.

Comment: I disagree. A quadrant is most-often used for a quarter of a disc. If you want a quarter of a circle, "quarter-circle" would be much less ambiguous and confusing than quadrant.